# Controller is not working for the bellow code?

Tags: angularjs, controller, state

controller.js code

```
angular.module('Zoho.controllers', [])
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $state) {
$scope.login = function(loginData) {
console.log(loginData);
}})
.controller('signUpController', function($scope, $state) {
$scope.signUp = function(signUpData) {
console.log(signUpData);
}})
```

app.js

```
angular.module('Zoho', 
['ui.router','Zoho.controllers','Zoho.services','Zoho.directive'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');      
$stateProvider
.state('login',{
url: '/login',
templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
controller : 'loginController'
})
.state('signUp',{
url: '/signup',
templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
controller : 'signUpController'
});
```

Here only the login part is executing but signup is not working, Im using both signup and login code in a single page with ng-show and ng-hide methods

login.html

```
<div class="container-fluid login" ng-show="showDiv">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" ng-model="loginData.username" required="required"/>
    <input placeholder="Mobile" type="number" ng-model="loginData.mobile" required="required"/>
    <button class="btn-signUp" ng-click="login(loginData)">Login <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
    <p>New User <button class="btn-link" ng-click="showDiv=false">SignUp</button></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid login" ng-hide="showDiv">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <h1 class="title">Register</h1>
    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" ng-model="signUpData.name" required="required"/>
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" ng-model="signUpData.username" required="required"/>
    <input placeholder="Mobile" type="number" ng-model="signUpData.mobile" required="required"/>
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" ng-model="signUpData.email" required="required"/>
    <button class="btn-signUp" ng-click="signUp(signUpData)">SignUp  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></button>
    <p>Already User<button class="btn-link" ng-click="showDiv=true">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your default view? also post login.html code

Comment: default view is register

Comment: can u add what is the error ? also have you initialized your app with ng-app?

Comment: Yes, I have initiallized ng-app,   Its not showing any error, but its not displaying the content from register form when i do the console.log, Its showing the content from login only,